# three.js strange behaviour on transparent materials

Tags: three.js

Am working with the three.js and am created a scene with the House , which have the lots of door/windows on the wall , and inside the rooms there is some living things like chairs, sofas and so on, all of them are seperate mesh and which is combined as single House object , i got neraly what am expecting , but am facing some issue on the materials am having for the walls

i have attached 2 image which illustare my problem, also here am explain what am getting

Pic 1:
my model looks nice from the long shot of camera, i can see the wall attached with the doors/windows inside the room i can see the sofas

Pic 2:
while look into my room from the attached doors/windows on the wall, the other side wall get disappeared it looks transparent , but i can see the doors/windows on that wall

am not sure what is wrong with my wall

and my code is follows:

```
function wall_fill(type,no_of_walls,wall_no,inner_filltype,inner_fill,outer_filltype,outer_fill,left_filltype,left_fill,right_filltype,right_fill,top_filltype,top_fill,bottom_filltype,bottom_fill,front_filltype,front_fill,back_filltype,back_fill)
    {            
        var materials,inner_material,outer_material,left_material,right_material,top_material,bottom_material,front_material,back_material;

        // inner wall
        if(inner_filltype    ==    'texture')
        {
            var inner_texture            =    THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/'+inner_fill );
            inner_texture.anisotropy    =     renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            inner_texture.wrapS         =     inner_texture.wrapT    =    THREE.RepeatWrapping;                
            inner_material    =    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: inner_texture,transparent : true,transparency : 1.0,opacity: 1.5, overdraw: 0.5});
        }
        else if(inner_filltype    ==    'color')
        {
            inner_fill    =    parseInt(inner_fill);
            inner_material    =    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: inner_fill,transparent: false,opacity: 1.5, overdraw: 0.5,side: THREE.DoubleSide })
        }
        else
        {
            var inner_texture            =    THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/trans.png' );
            inner_texture.anisotropy    =     renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            inner_texture.wrapS         =     inner_texture.wrapT    =    THREE.RepeatWrapping;                
            //inner_material    =    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: inner_texture,transparent: true,opacity: 1.5, overdraw: 0.5 });
            inner_material    =    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xd6d6d6,transparent: true,opacity: -1.5, overdraw: 0.5 })
        }

        // outer wall
        if(outer_filltype    ==    'texture')
        {
            var outer_texture            =    THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/'+outer_fill );
            outer_texture.anisotropy    =     renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            outer_texture.wrapS         =     outer_texture.wrapT    =    THREE.RepeatWrapping;    
            outer_material    =    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: outer_texture,transparent: true, opacity: 1.5,overdraw: 0.5,  });
        }
        else if(outer_filltype    ==    'color')
        {
            outer_fill    =    parseInt(outer_fill);
            outer_material    =    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: outer_fill,transparent: true, opacity: 1.5, overdraw: 0.5,side: THREE.DoubleSide });
        }
        else
        {
            var outer_texture            =    THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/trans.png');
            outer_texture.anisotropy    =     renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            outer_texture.wrapS         =     outer_texture.wrapT    =    THREE.RepeatWrapping;    
            //outer_material    =    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: outer_texture,transparent: true, opacity: 1.5,overdraw: 0.5 });
            outer_material    =    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xd6d6d6,transparent: true, opacity: -1.5, overdraw: 0.5 });
        }

        // left wall
        if(left_filltype    ==    'texture')
        {
            var left_texture            =    THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/'+left_fill );
            left_texture.anisotropy        =     renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            left_texture.wrapS             =     left_texture.wrapT    =    THREE.RepeatWrapping;    
            left_material    =    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: left_texture,transparent: true, opacity: 1.5,overdraw: 0.5 });
        }
        else if(left_filltype    ==    'color')
        {
            left_fill    =    parseInt(left_fill);
            left_material    =    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: left_fill,transparent: true, opacity: 1.5, overdraw: 0.5,side: THREE.DoubleSide });
        }
        else
        {
            var left_texture            =    THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/trans.png');
            left_texture.anisotropy        =     renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            left_texture.wrapS             =     left_texture.wrapT    =    THREE.RepeatWrapping;    
            //left_material    =    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: left_texture,transparent: true, opacity: 1.5,overdraw: 0.5 });            
            left_material    =    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xd6d6d6,transparent: true, opacity: -1.5, overdraw: 0.5 });
        }

        // right wall
        if(right_filltype    ==    'texture')
        {
            var right_texture            =    THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/'+right_fill );
            right_texture.anisotropy    =     renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            right_texture.wrapS         =     right_texture.wrapT    =    THREE.RepeatWrapping;    
            right_material    =    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: right_texture,transparent: true, opacity: 1.5,overdraw: 0.5 });
        }
        else if(right_filltype    ==    'color')
        {
            right_fill    =    parseInt(right_fill);
            right_material    =    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: right_fill,transparent: true, opacity: 1.5, overdraw: 0.5,side: THREE.DoubleSide });
        }
        else
        {
            var right_texture            =    THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/trans.png');
            right_texture.anisotropy    =     renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            right_texture.wrapS         =     right_texture.wrapT    =    THREE.RepeatWrapping;    
            //right_material    =    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: right_texture,transparent: true, opacity: 1.5,overdraw: 0.5 });
            right_material    =    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xd6d6d6,transparent: true, opacity: -1.5, overdraw: 0.5 });
        }

        // top wall
        if(top_filltype    ==    'texture')
        {
            var top_texture                =    THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/'+top_fill );
            top_texture.anisotropy        =     renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            top_texture.wrapS             =     top_texture.wrapT    =    THREE.RepeatWrapping;    
            top_material    =    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: top_texture,transparent: true, opacity: 1.5,overdraw: 0.5 });
        }
        else if(top_filltype    ==    'color')
        {
            top_fill    =    parseInt(top_fill);
            top_material    =    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: top_fill,transparent: true, opacity: 1.5, overdraw: 0.5,side: THREE.DoubleSide });
        }
        else
        {
            var top_texture            =    THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/trans.png');
            top_texture.anisotropy    =     renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            top_texture.wrapS         =     top_texture.wrapT    =    THREE.RepeatWrapping;    
            //top_material    =    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: top_texture,transparent: true, opacity: 1.5,overdraw: 0.5 });
            top_material    =    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xd6d6d6,transparent: true, opacity: -1.5, overdraw: 0.5 });
        }

        // bottom wall
        if(bottom_filltype    ==    'texture')
        {
            var bottom_texture            =    THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/'+bottom_fill );
            bottom_texture.anisotropy    =     renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            bottom_texture.wrapS         =     bottom_texture.wrapT    =    THREE.RepeatWrapping;    
            bottom_material    =    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: bottom_texture,transparent: true, opacity: 1.5,overdraw: 0.5 });
        }
        else if(bottom_filltype    ==    'color')
        {
            bottom_fill    =    parseInt(bottom_fill);
            bottom_material    =    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: bottom_fill,transparent: true, opacity: 1.5, overdraw: 0.5,side: THREE.DoubleSide });
        }
        else
        {
            var bottom_texture            =    THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/trans.png');
            bottom_texture.anisotropy    =     renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            bottom_texture.wrapS         =     bottom_texture.wrapT    =    THREE.RepeatWrapping;    
            //bottom_material    =    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: bottom_texture,transparent: true, opacity: 1.5,overdraw: 0.5 });
            bottom_material    =    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xd6d6d6,transparent: true, opacity: -1.5, overdraw: 0.5 });
        }

        // front wall
        if(front_filltype    ==    'texture')
        {
            var front_texture            =    THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/'+front_fill );
            front_texture.anisotropy    =     renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            front_texture.wrapS         =     front_texture.wrapT    =    THREE.RepeatWrapping;    
            front_material    =    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: front_texture,transparent: true, opacity: 1.5,overdraw: 0.5 });
        }
        else if(front_filltype    ==    'color')
        {
            front_fill    =    parseInt(front_fill);
            front_material    =    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: front_fill,transparent: true, opacity: 1.5, overdraw: 0.5 ,side: THREE.DoubleSide});
        }
        else
        {
            var front_texture            =    THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/trans.png');
            front_texture.anisotropy    =     renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            front_texture.wrapS         =     front_texture.wrapT    =    THREE.RepeatWrapping;    
            //front_material    =    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: front_texture,transparent: true, opacity: 1.5,overdraw: 0.5 });
            front_material    =    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xd6d6d6,transparent: true, opacity: -1.5, overdraw: 0.5 });
        }

        // back wall
        if(back_filltype    ==    'texture')
        {
            var back_texture            =    THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/'+back_fill );
            back_texture.anisotropy    =     renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            back_texture.wrapS         =     back_texture.wrapT    =    THREE.RepeatWrapping;    
            back_material    =    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: back_texture,transparent: true, opacity: 1.5,overdraw: 0.5 });
        }
        else if(back_filltype    ==    'color')
        {
            back_fill    =    parseInt(back_fill);
            back_material    =    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: back_fill,transparent: true, opacity: 1.5, overdraw: 0.5 ,side: THREE.DoubleSide});
        }
        else
        {
            var back_texture            =    THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/trans.png');
            back_texture.anisotropy    =     renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            back_texture.wrapS         =     back_texture.wrapT    =    THREE.RepeatWrapping;    
            //back_material    =    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: back_texture,transparent: true, opacity: 1.5,overdraw: 0.5 });
            back_material    =    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xd6d6d6,transparent: true, opacity: -1.5, overdraw: 0.5 });
        }

        var left,right,top,bottom,front,back;
            if( wall_no    ==    1)
            {
                left    =    left_material;
                right    =    right_material;
                top        =    top_material;
                bottom    =    bottom_material;
                front    =    inner_material;
                back    =    outer_material;
            }

            if( wall_no    ==    2)
            {
                left    =    outer_material;
                right    =    inner_material;
                top        =    top_material;
                bottom    =    bottom_material;
                front    =    front_material;
                back    =    back_material;
            }

            if( wall_no    ==    3)
            {
                left    =    left_material;
                right    =    right_material;
                top        =    top_material;
                bottom    =    bottom_material;
                front    =    outer_material;
                back    =    inner_material;
            }

            if( wall_no    ==    4)
            {
                left    =    inner_material;
                right    =    outer_material;
                top        =    top_material;
                bottom    =    bottom_material;
                front    =    front_material;
                back    =    back_material;
            }

            materials = [
                      left,    // Left side
                      right, // Right side
                      top,     // Top side    
                      bottom,// Bottom side    
                      front, // Front side
                      back    // Back side
                    ];

        var material    =    new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
        return material;
    }
```

[image: Pic 1]
[image: Pic 2]

**Updated function**

```
function wall_fill(type,no_of_walls,wall_no,inner_filltype,inner_fill,outer_filltype,outer_fill,left_filltype,left_fill,right_filltype,right_fill,top_filltype,top_fill,bottom_filltype,bottom_fill,front_filltype,front_fill,back_filltype,back_fill)
    {           
        var materials,inner_material,outer_material,left_material,right_material,top_material,bottom_material,front_material,back_material;

        // inner wall
        if(inner_filltype   ==  'texture')
        {
            var inner_texture           =   THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/'+inner_fill );
            inner_texture.anisotropy    =   renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            inner_texture.wrapS         =   inner_texture.wrapT =   THREE.RepeatWrapping;               
            inner_material  =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: inner_texture,transparent : true, opacity:0.5,side: THREE.DoubleSide });
        }
        else if(inner_filltype  ==  'color')
        {
            inner_fill  =   parseInt(inner_fill);
            inner_material  =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: inner_fill,transparent: true,opacity:0.5 })
        }
        else
        {
            var inner_texture           =   THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/trans.png' );
            inner_texture.anisotropy    =   renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            inner_texture.wrapS         =   inner_texture.wrapT =   THREE.RepeatWrapping;               
            //inner_material    =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: inner_texture,transparent: true });
            inner_material  =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xd6d6d6,transparent: true,opacity:0.5 })
        }

        // outer wall
        if(outer_filltype   ==  'texture')
        {
            var outer_texture           =   THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/'+outer_fill );
            outer_texture.anisotropy    =   renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            outer_texture.wrapS         =   outer_texture.wrapT =   THREE.RepeatWrapping;   
            outer_material  =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: outer_texture,transparent: true,opacity:0.5,side: THREE.DoubleSide});
        }
        else if(outer_filltype  ==  'color')
        {
            outer_fill  =   parseInt(outer_fill);
            outer_material  =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: outer_fill,transparent: true, opacity:0.5});
        }
        else
        {
            var outer_texture           =   THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/trans.png');
            outer_texture.anisotropy    =   renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            outer_texture.wrapS         =   outer_texture.wrapT =   THREE.RepeatWrapping;   
            //outer_material    =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: outer_texture,transparent: true });
            outer_material  =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xd6d6d6,transparent: true ,opacity:0.5});
        }

        // left wall
        if(left_filltype    ==  'texture')
        {
            var left_texture            =   THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/'+left_fill );
            left_texture.anisotropy     =   renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            left_texture.wrapS          =   left_texture.wrapT  =   THREE.RepeatWrapping;   
            left_material   =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: left_texture,transparent: true ,opacity:0.5});
        }
        else if(left_filltype   ==  'color')
        {
            left_fill   =   parseInt(left_fill);
            left_material   =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: left_fill,transparent: true,opacity:0.5 });
        }
        else
        {
            var left_texture            =   THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/trans.png');
            left_texture.anisotropy     =   renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            left_texture.wrapS          =   left_texture.wrapT  =   THREE.RepeatWrapping;   
            //left_material =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: left_texture,transparent: true });            
            left_material   =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xd6d6d6,transparent: true,opacity:0.5 });
        }

        // right wall
        if(right_filltype   ==  'texture')
        {
            var right_texture           =   THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/'+right_fill );
            right_texture.anisotropy    =   renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            right_texture.wrapS         =   right_texture.wrapT =   THREE.RepeatWrapping;   
            right_material  =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: right_texture,transparent: true ,opacity:0.5});
        }
        else if(right_filltype  ==  'color')
        {
            right_fill  =   parseInt(right_fill);
            right_material  =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: right_fill,transparent: true,opacity:0.5 });
        }
        else
        {
            var right_texture           =   THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/trans.png');
            right_texture.anisotropy    =   renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            right_texture.wrapS         =   right_texture.wrapT =   THREE.RepeatWrapping;   
            //right_material    =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: right_texture,transparent: true });
            right_material  =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xd6d6d6,transparent: true,opacity:0.5});
        }

        // top wall
        if(top_filltype ==  'texture')
        {
            var top_texture             =   THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/'+top_fill );
            top_texture.anisotropy      =   renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            top_texture.wrapS           =   top_texture.wrapT   =   THREE.RepeatWrapping;   
            top_material    =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: top_texture,transparent: true,opacity:0.5 });
        }
        else if(top_filltype    ==  'color')
        {
            top_fill    =   parseInt(top_fill);
            top_material    =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: top_fill,transparent: true,opacity:0.5});
        }
        else
        {
            var top_texture         =   THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/trans.png');
            top_texture.anisotropy  =   renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            top_texture.wrapS       =   top_texture.wrapT   =   THREE.RepeatWrapping;   
            //top_material  =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: top_texture,transparent: true });
            top_material    =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xd6d6d6,transparent: true,opacity:0.5 });
        }

        // bottom wall
        if(bottom_filltype  ==  'texture')
        {
            var bottom_texture          =   THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/'+bottom_fill );
            bottom_texture.anisotropy   =   renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            bottom_texture.wrapS        =   bottom_texture.wrapT    =   THREE.RepeatWrapping;   
            bottom_material =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: bottom_texture,transparent: true,opacity:0.5 });
        }
        else if(bottom_filltype ==  'color')
        {
            bottom_fill =   parseInt(bottom_fill);
            bottom_material =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: bottom_fill,transparent: true, opacity:0.5});
        }
        else
        {
            var bottom_texture          =   THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/trans.png');
            bottom_texture.anisotropy   =   renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            bottom_texture.wrapS        =   bottom_texture.wrapT    =   THREE.RepeatWrapping;   
            //bottom_material   =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: bottom_texture,transparent: true });
            bottom_material =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xd6d6d6,transparent: true,opacity:0.5 });
        }

        // front wall
        if(front_filltype   ==  'texture')
        {
            var front_texture           =   THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/'+front_fill );
            front_texture.anisotropy    =   renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            front_texture.wrapS         =   front_texture.wrapT =   THREE.RepeatWrapping;   
            front_material  =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: front_texture,transparent: true,opacity:0.5 });
        }
        else if(front_filltype  ==  'color')
        {
            front_fill  =   parseInt(front_fill);
            front_material  =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: front_fill,transparent: true ,opacity:0.5});
        }
        else
        {
            var front_texture           =   THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/trans.png');
            front_texture.anisotropy    =   renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            front_texture.wrapS         =   front_texture.wrapT =   THREE.RepeatWrapping;   
            //front_material    =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: front_texture,transparent: true });
            front_material  =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xd6d6d6,transparent: true,opacity:0.5 });
        }

        // back wall
        if(back_filltype    ==  'texture')
        {
            var back_texture            =   THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/'+back_fill );
            back_texture.anisotropy =   renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            back_texture.wrapS      =   back_texture.wrapT  =   THREE.RepeatWrapping;   
            back_material   =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: back_texture,transparent: true,opacity:0.5, });
        }
        else if(back_filltype   ==  'color')
        {
            back_fill   =   parseInt(back_fill);
            back_material   =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: back_fill,transparent: true ,opacity:0.5});
        }
        else
        {
            var back_texture            =   THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( baseurl+'uploads/textures/'+type+'/trans.png');
            back_texture.anisotropy =   renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
            back_texture.wrapS      =   back_texture.wrapT  =   THREE.RepeatWrapping;   
            //back_material =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: back_texture,transparent: true });
            back_material   =   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xd6d6d6,transparent: true ,opacity:0.5});
        }

        var left,right,top,bottom,front,back;
            if( wall_no ==  1)
            {
                left    =   left_material;
                right   =   right_material;
                top     =   top_material;
                bottom  =   bottom_material;
                front   =   inner_material;
                back    =   outer_material;
            }

            if( wall_no ==  2)
            {
                left    =   outer_material;
                right   =   inner_material;
                top     =   top_material;
                bottom  =   bottom_material;
                front   =   front_material;
                back    =   back_material;
            }

            if( wall_no ==  3)
            {
                left    =   left_material;
                right   =   right_material;
                top     =   top_material;
                bottom  =   bottom_material;
                front   =   outer_material;
                back    =   inner_material;
            }

            if( wall_no ==  4)
            {
                left    =   inner_material;
                right   =   outer_material;
                top     =   top_material;
                bottom  =   bottom_material;
                front   =   front_material;
                back    =   back_material;
            }

            materials = [
                      left, // Left side 
                      right, // Right side 
                      top,   // Top side    
                      bottom,// Bottom side 
                      front, // Front side 
                      back  // Back side 
                    ];

        var material    =   new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials); 
        return material;
    }
```

still am getting the same set of result

Comment: 1. Why is `opacity = - 1.5 or + 1.5`? 2. Why are your setting `overdraw = 0.5`? 3. Are you merging your geometries into one? 4. Why are you using `MeshFaceMaterials`? 5. Are you using `WebGLRenderer`?

Comment: 1. `Opacity=-1.5,1.5` is working to me, if i set 0 to 1 i don't see any changes somehow, so i leaved is as it is, 2. i tried without `overdraw`,so no sense about it,3.Yes 4.i thought `MeshFaceMaterials` is nice one so am using it 5. yes `WebGLRenderer`

Comment: Hi @WestLangley any reply for question ????

Comment: 1. Why is `opacity` 0.5? 2. Why are you setting `anisotropy`? 3. Why are you setting `wrapS` and `wrapT`? 4. Why is `transparent` true?

Comment: 1.opacity 0.5 : i want the full transparent materials, which exactly looks the door space 2.When am looking from distance the textures are looking blurry so using `anisotropy` 4.i need the materials to wrap around the full geometry so using 4. i need the transparent materials so am using

Comment: This appears to be a self-transparency problem, caused because you merged your geometry. You may have better luck if you keep your geometries separate -- at least the transparent doors. Do an experiment.

Comment: @WestLangley sure thanks for the hint i will experiment this

Answer (score 1):

What I have done in my THREE.js application is disable transparency completely on all your materials. Then I enable "alphaTest" parameter on my materials. What this will do is disable smooth alpha, and use a cut-off value for either transparent, or not transparent.

Here are my settings for materials:

```
specular: new THREE.Color( 0x101010 ),
shininess: 40,
alphaTest: 0.15,
color: new THREE.Color( 0xffffff ),
metal: true,
wrapAround: true,
side: THREE.DoubleSide
```

With this it is safe to set `transparent: false`.

If none of your objects are semi-transparent this will solve your issue. If they are semi-transparent, you have to implement much more complicated algorithms to draw transparency properly (see depth-peeling, or other methods such as drawing objects in specific orderings).

Comment: Hi @beiller, thanks for the reply, but still i can't see any changes except that my materials are full white now